# Why is the map from $A^n$ to $M$ a surjective homomorphism?

Tags: commutative-algebra

How can one do the problem 1.3.11 b in *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*? I have read basics of commutative algebra but this one seems to be too difficult.

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unit which is a complete ring for the $I$-adic topology, where $I$ is an ideal of $A$. Let $(M_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be $A$-modules such that $I^{n+1}M_n=0$ and that there exist surjective homomorphism $\pi_n:M_{n+1}\to M_n$ with $\operatorname{Ker} (\pi_n)=I^{n+1}M_{n+1}$. Let $M=\varprojlim_nM_n$ and denote the surjective canonical homomorphism by $u_n:M\to M_n$.

Let us suppose that $M_0$ is generated over $A$ by a finite number of elements $e_{0,1},\ldots e_{0,m}$. Let $e_1,\ldots,e_m\in M$ be such that $u_0(e_i)=e_{0,i}$, and define $\phi_n:A^m\to M_n$ by $(a_1,\ldots,a_m)\mapsto \sum_ia_iu_n(e_i)$. How can one show that $\phi_n$ is surjective?

I think it might have something to do with universal property but I am unable to figure it out. I also tried to select $A=\mathbb Z$ but even this special case is too difficult for me. I would be glad for any hints and even special cases would help me. I was also wondering if here complete mean separated and complete as it was said in page 17 that the author omits the term separated.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level.

Comment: Isn't that simply an inductive argument? Let $\phi_0$ be defined as above. Noting that $(\pi_{n + 1} \circ \phi_n)(a) = \pi_{n + 1}(\sum_{i = 1}^m a_i u_n(e_i)) = \sum_{i = 1}^m a_i \pi_n(u_n(e_i)) = \sum_{i = 1}^m a_i u_{n + 1}(e_i) = \phi_{n + 1}(a)$ for $a = (a_1, ..., a_m) \in A^m$, we get - since $\phi_0$ and $\pi_1$ are surjective -, that $\phi_1 = \pi_1 \circ \phi_0$ is surjective. Then proceed inductively.

Comment: I'm not sure. Could anyone verify @Steven's idea.